# Implicit declaration of function 'sum' is invalid in C99

Tags: c, xcode

I've been looking for a solution to this but haven't found anything that will help.
I'm getting the following errors:

```
Implicit declaration of function 'sum' is invalid in C99
```

```
Implicit declaration of function 'average' is invalid in C99
```

```
Conflicting types for 'average'
```

Has anyone experienced this before?  I'm trying to compile it in Xcode.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {

       @autoreleasepool
       {
          int wholeNumbers[5] = {2,3,5,7,9};
          int theSum = sum (wholeNumbers, 5);
          printf ("The sum is: %i ", theSum);
          float fractionalNumbers[3] = {16.9, 7.86, 3.4};
          float theAverage = average (fractionalNumbers, 3);
          printf ("and the average is: %f \n", theAverage);

       }
        return 0;
    }

    int sum (int values[], int count)
    {
       int i;
       int total = 0;
       for ( i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
          // add each value in the array to the total.
          total = total + values[i];
       }
       return total;
    }

    float average (float values[], int count )
    {
       int i;
       float total = 0.0;
       for ( i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
          // add each value in the array to the total.
          total = total + values[i];
       }
       // calculate the average.
       float average = (total / count);
       return average;
    }
```

Comment: Check this answer, worked like a charm for me!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221365/3063226

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add declaration for these two functions, or move the two function definitions before main.

Comment: Nope. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221365/3063226, the explanation and the solution are right there!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that by the time the compiler sees the code where you use `sum` it doesn`t know of any symbol with that name. You can forward declare it to fix the problem.

```
int sum (int values[], int count);
```

Put that before `main()`. This way, when the compiler sees the first use of `sum` it knows that it exists and must be implemented somewhere else. If it isn't then it will give a liner error.

Comment: I fixed it thanks you point me in the right direction. I also had to include: int sum (int values[], int count);
float average (float values[], int count ); above main()

Comment: I fixed it Nick thanks. I aslo had to add : float average (float values[], int count );