# How to change flags of a compiler in Xcode 6.3?

Tags: xcode, compilation, compiler-flags, xcode6.3

I'd like to change the compilers options (flags) of a project which is based on the "command line tool" project template from Xcode 6.3.

Basically, **I'd like to remove the `-lcurses` flag**  (which is added during compilation) when project is based on the "command line tool" project template.

I just can't find the correct path to the compiler's settings in Xcode 6.3.

Unfortunatelly all the sites I've browsed were about previous version of Xcode and it seems that the path has changed since then.

Comment: It could be configured in the target's "Link with libraries" section or under the target's project settings (in *Other Linker Flags* for example).

Comment: unfortunately, there is no `-lcurses` there. It is predefined somewhere else I guess.

Comment: It turns out that the flags might not be accesible directly. Nevertheless, there is a way to disbale all the additional modules/headers/libraries. More on that has been posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809959/how-to-disable-curses-h-header-a-part-of-stdio-h-in-xcode-6-3-osx-yosemite?lq=1.
One way or another, **I'm still curious whether one can directly modify the final flags Xcode adds to the compiler.**