# Prevent Xcode 6.3 from linking default libraries and headers when using project templates

Tags: ios, c, xcode, curses, xcode6.3

I'm building a project in Xcode 6.3. I based it on a `command line tool` project template. Is there a possibility to exclude the automatically added libraries of such paths and origins like for example `curses.h`?
Here the path:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/curses.h`

Where can I change the default settings of inclusion/exclusion of the default libraries loaded in the target of my project?

Thank you for any hints, since it is awfully hard to find something about it on the web.

Comment: What do you mean? `curses.h` is a header, not a library, and `libcurses` is not linked into your executable by default. What problem are you having that makes you want to exclude it?

Comment: In this question I am asking about disabling the headers and libraries which are linked to your project when you choose the `command line tool` template and note the `empty project` template. Here is a more specific question where the origin of the problem is explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809959/how-to-disable-curses-h-library-in-xcode-6-3-osx-yosemite-to-avoid-conflicting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can easily disable all the additional modules in Xcode's *Build Settings*:

*Build Settings > Apple LLVM 6.1 - Language - Modules > Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)*

and set it to *No*.

(a broader answer was posted by Thomas Dickey here: [How to disable "curses.h" header (a part of "stdio.h in Xcode 6.3 OSX Yosemite) to avoid conflicting function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809959/how-to-disable-curses-h-header-a-part-of-stdio-h-in-xcode-6-3-osx-yosemite?lq=1))