# 'stdarg.h' file not found error

Tags: xcode, build-error, xcode6.3.1

I recently upgraded to xcode 6.3.1. I tried creating a sample project from "Master Detail application" template, but build failed with the below error.

- Device - Universal
- language - swift
- Not using Core Data

Errors:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:32:10:
>   error: **'stdarg.h' file not found**
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/usr/include/os/activity.h:38:9:
>   error: declaration of **'uint64_t' must be imported from module
>   'ObjectiveC.runtime' before it is required** typedef uint64_t
>   os_activity_t;

I am new to development using Xcode.

Comment: Are you sure Xcode is not damaged? Have you installed the developer tools? Probably installing them or reinstalling Xcode helps.

Comment: Yes.. It worked.. After completely removing xcode and reinstalling it works.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I will post this suggestion as an answer, since it solved your problem. If you want you can accept it. This makes it clear that your problem was solved and will give some reputation to you and me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your installation of Xcode (or the simulator) is damaged.

You can try reinstalling the developer tools, or completely reinstall Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find out whether you've got modules for Objective-C enabled.

You can check it in here (follow the path):

- Build Settings
- section Apple LLVM 6.1 - Language - Modules
- Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)

The answer to this question might be a clue as well: [How to disable "curses.h" header (a part of "stdio.h in Xcode 6.3 OSX Yosemite) to avoid conflicting function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809959/how-to-disable-curses-h-header-a-part-of-stdio-h-in-xcode-6-3-osx-yosemite)

Comment: I checked the settings. By default "Enable Modules is set to YES". Still seeing this error