# Running AOSP on MAC: stdarg.h error

Tags: android, android-source

I have the source code for android-5.0.0_r7.0.1. After doing:

```
make -j4
```

I keep getting this:

```
error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from system/core/include/cutils/log.h:1,
             from system/core/include/utils/KeyedVector.h:24,
             from frameworks/native/include/input/Input.h:26,
             from frameworks/native/include/input/InputDevice.h:20,
             from frameworks/native/libs/input/InputDevice.cpp:23:
system/core/include/log/log.h:35:20: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/validatekeymaps_intermediates/Main.o] Error 1 
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinput_intermediates/Keyboard.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinput_intermediates/InputDevice.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj32/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinput_intermediates/Input.o] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (01:32 (mm:ss)) ####
```

I have looked at the google groups and other stack overflow questions, but I cannot seem to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Looks like you don't have `stdarg.h`. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/stdarg.3.html What compiler are you using and how did you install it?

Comment: I dint install a specific compiler on my own. I have installed Xcode 6.4 which I believe uses clang (I think) @tekknolagi

Comment: See: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/45695 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172986/stdarg-h-file-not-found-error. They seem to suggest reinstalling XCode / command-line tools.

Comment: Ok I had looked at the first link before posting here. They say:Please run the following commands and attach the main.log file immediately afterwards:

% sudo port clean libiconv
% sudo port install libiconv     How do I attach the main.log file? This seemed to work for the OP, I'm just not sure how to do the bit about main.log @tekknolagi

Comment: Well since you are not using `libiconv` for Android (hopefully?), you should just avoid that.

Comment: > I just did a complete wipe and reinstall of XCode and CLT (by wipe I mean moved to thrash then manually deleting all files mentioned in /var/db/receipts/*{DevSDK,CLTools}*.bom) and installed XCode from App Store and CLT by doing xcode-select --install.

Comment: How do I access and delete the files in /var/db/receipts/*{DevSDK,CLTools}*.bom) ? @tekknolagi

Comment: Presumably you are in the terminal — you can quite literally type: `rm /var/db/receipts/*{DevSDK,CLTools}*.bom` to remove them. Make sure that is all in one line and exactly as I have it, though.

Comment: @tekknolagi according to one of the Google groups the AOSP code doesn't support Yosemite + XCode 6.4 so I'm trying to run it on my Ubuntu VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Meteorite

Well, ultimately after googling I discovered the AOSP for some reason did not support the latest version of Xcode tools and OS X. I dualbooted windows 7 with ubuntu, and did the whole process. And when I did the make command on ubuntu I typed: make -k -i -B. That is, I gave it the keep going, ignore make errors and build unconditionally flags.